# getWaypointMissionOperator().uploadMission on Matrice 600 fails

Tags: dji-sdk

`getWaypointMissionOperator().uploadMission`

Fails randomly when uploading waypoints to a Matrice 600. What could be causing this issue?

This is my code:

```
    private void uploadWayPointMission() {
        getWaypointMissionOperator().uploadMission(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DJIError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    healthData.get("misionData").healthStatus = true;
                    healthData.get("misionData").healthInfo = "Ok";
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            uploadTimer =  new CountDownTimer(10000, 10) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    mUploadFPDialog.setProgress((10000 - (int)millisUntilFinished)/100);
                                    showUploadProgressDialog();
                                }
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    hideUploadProgressDialog();
                                    showChecklistDialog();
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    setResultToToast("Failure uploading mission");
                    healthData.get("misionData").healthStatus = false;
                    healthData.get("misionData").healthInfo = error.getDescription();
                    getWaypointMissionOperator().retryUploadMission(null);
                    enableFlightPlanEdition = true;
                    disableEnableFlightPlanEdition(enableFlightPlanEdition);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have tested it in a Mavic and in a Matrice 600. While there are no problems with Mavic (mission is always uploaded), when I test it in a Matrice, the method getWaypointMissionOperator().uploadMission fails.

I don't know if this method is incompatible with Matrice 600. I have looked for a list with compatible functionality per every DJI drone but I haven't found any, but if such a list exists it would be very welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Dji Inspire 1. On the Mavic everything works. The first and the last waypoints are the same (I just copy the first one) but that prevents the mission upload. I just increase the last waypoint height by 1 meter (3 feets) and it loads ok.